# How to server static files from an php-fpm image over an nginx image

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, static-files

I have a web app based on the Symfony framework.

I have an php-fpm image with all the php and asset files.

Now I want to serve the files over a nginx container. The php part is easy. But how can I serve the static files included in the php-fpm image?

I tried to create a volume that is mounted by both containers. But after docker copied the files from the image into the volume after the first start the files are not updated any more after I update the image.

I could copy the files after any start of the container from a second dir into the volume to solve this problem but I dont want this overhead.

Does any one has a good idea who I can share the static files so that they can be served directly by the nginx container?

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.15-alpine
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
            - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
            - static-content:/var/www/app/web
        command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"

    php:
        image: pbnl/scotoobo-php:dev
        volumes:
            - static-content:/var/www/app/web
        environment:
            - database_host=db
volumes:
  static-content:
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
RUN groupmod -g 1000 www-data

ENV APP_ENV=prod
ENV SYMFONY_ENV=prod

# install system basics
# install some php extensions
# install composer

WORKDIR /var/www/app

# copy the source code
COPY composer.* ./
COPY app app
COPY bin bin
COPY src src
COPY web web-tmp

# set up correct permissions to run the next composer commands 
RUN mkdir var
RUN mkdir var/logs
RUN mkdir var/cache
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
RUN find /var/www/ -type d -exec chmod 775 "{}" \;
RUN find /var/www/ -type f -exec chmod 664 "{}" \;
RUN find /var/www -type d -exec chmod g+s "{}" \;

# generate the autoloaders and run composer scripts
USER www-data
RUN composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction --no-scripts
```